# Does sortrows always preserve the original ordering within sorting groups?

Tags: matlab, sorting

MATLAB's `sortrows` function seems to leave ordering unchanged within each sorting group. Does anyone know whether this is actually true, as I cannot find any documentation supporting this.

Using MATLAB's provided example for [`sortrows`](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html):

```
A = {'Germany' 'Lukas'; 'USA' 'William'; 'USA' 'Andrew'; ...
'Germany' 'Andreas'; 'USA' 'Olivia'; 'Germany' 'Julia'} 

A = 

    'Germany'    'Lukas'  
    'USA'        'William'
    'USA'        'Andrew' 
    'Germany'    'Andreas'
    'USA'        'Olivia' 
    'Germany'    'Julia'
```

and applying `sortrows(A, [1])`

```
ans = 

    'Germany'    'Lukas'  
    'Germany'    'Andreas'
    'Germany'    'Julia'  
    'USA'        'William'
    'USA'        'Andrew' 
    'USA'        'Olivia'
```

see that in the original data, `Germany` in the first column is followed by `Lukas`, `Andreas`, `Julia` in the second column reading from top to bottom. This is preserved in the end result.

Is this behaviour guaranteed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Matlab uses [quick sort](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96656-what-type-of-sort-does-the-sort-function-in-matlab-perform) which is stable (if they don't employ some data specific optimizations). For the most part, I'd assume that Matlab uses stable sort, but cannot be sure without looking at the source.

Your best bet is contacting Matlab tech support to make sure that their sort algorithm is indeed stable, and if they have any plans to change that in the future.

`sortrows` uses the internal sort. You can read the source:

```
>> edit sortrows
```

edit: more [info](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/an-adventure-of-sortsbehind-the-scenes-of-a-matlab-upgrade.html)

Comment: thank you, this was exactly the sort of answer I was looking for. Your suggestion to ask Matlab support is a good one.

Comment: Could you also please add this link to your answer: http://au.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/an-adventure-of-sortsbehind-the-scenes-of-a-matlab-upgrade.html

Comment: Good suggestion. Link added.

Comment: Quicksort is **not** stable.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know if `sortrows` is stable, the docs don’t say (or I couldn’t find it in the docs).

But you can always enforce stability by adding a column with sorted integers, for example `1:N`, and sort on this column as a second value (so sort on `[1,3]` if the new column is the 3rd one).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's what the `1` means. If you were to put in `[1,2]`, it would sort the second row.

Comment: thank you, do you have any references that can back this up? For example, this sort of behaviour is not guaranteed in SQL.